# VBA code keeps adding paragraph marks after replacing text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have simple Word document with a table that goes on for about 10 pages.

The table has three columns.

I needed to select all the rows of the first column, remove the spaces and add an asterisk before. Eg.: "JOHN DOE" becomes "*JOHNDOE"

I have this piece of code:

```
Dim tbl As Table
Dim row As row
Dim cell As cell
Dim text As String
Dim newText As String
Dim undoRecord As undoRecord
    
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1) ' Change 1 to the index of the table you want to modify
Set undoRecord = Application.undoRecord
undoRecord.StartCustomRecord "Correct Names"
    
For Each row In tbl.Rows
    Set cell = row.Cells(1)
    text = cell.Range.text
    newText = "*" & Replace(text, " ", "")
    cell.Range.text = newText ' Overwrite the existing text with the new text
Next row
undoRecord.EndCustomRecord
```

He does the job nice and done, now every cell has a paragraph mark (PM) in the end.

For example: "JOHN DOE" becomes "*JOHNDOE[PM]"

What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `cell.Range.text` includes the end of cell marker which is a compound character that includes a paragraph mark (carriage return).

To avoid this you need to exclude the end of cell mark by replacing

`text = cell.Range.text`

with

`text = Left(cell.Range.text, Len(cell.Range.text) - 2)`

Comment: Nice, it worked! I just had to do a little tweaking: text = cell.Range.text should only be cell.Range.text, else it throws an error!

Thank you!